# How much memory will a Windows file-server be able to use effectively

Tags: windows-server-2008, 64-bit, file-server

In the near future we will be moving our fileserver to a newer box that will be running Windows 2008R2.  I want to know how much memory Windows will be able to use for a system that is just a file-server.

In searching around I found an [old document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742613.aspx) for Windows 2000 that mentions the maximum size of the file-system cache is 960MB.  I suspect this limit no longer applies, but is there a new limit?

The file server will be just a standard Windows fileserver.  It will have 1TB of attached storage.  The large majority of the of the files accessed during the day are just typical Office documents.  There are 80-100 people usually using the fileserver during a typical day.  This system will only be used as a file server, it doesn't have any other roles.

- In Windows 2008r2 is there any hard limits for the filesystem cache?  What are they?
- The server we will be re-using for this purpose currently has 4GB of memory, but it can be maxed out at 16GB.  Is there any value in doing this for a Windows file-server?
- Are there any performance counters can I look at on the existing 2003 fileserver that will tell me if adding more memory will be worthwhile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Server 2008 can use all of the available RAM in a system to increase performance. Under 2003 that limit in size had a default value and a max size governed by SystemCacheDirtyPageThreshold.  2008 has a completely different management scheme and because of that there is an optional service ([Microsoft Windows Dynamic Cache Service](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e24ade0a-5efe-43c8-b9c3-5d0ecb2f39af&displaylang=en)) you can use to manage the cache size.  This service will run on 2003 but frankly is rarely a problem on 2003.

More RAM will always be helpful but the counter to look at would be hard page faults.  Cache is what makes that number closer to 0.